# Input Layer for Conv1D in Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, conv1d

Let me explain my problem and the dataset a bit. In my dataset, i have hourly measurements of a variable `x` and 7 more columns representing the day of the week that that measurment was taken as dummy variables. So, it is something like this:

```
DateTime          x   Mon Tue Wed Thur Fri Sat Sun
2017/01/01 00:00  10   0   0   0   0    0   0   1
2017/01/01 01:00  15   0   0   0   0    0   0   1
2017/01/01 02:00  21   0   0   0   0    0   0   1
             ...
2017/01/01 23:00  32   0   0   0   0    0   0   1
2017/01/02 00:00  17   1   0   0   0    0   0   0
2017/01/02 01:00  19   1   0   0   0    0   0   0
2017/01/02 02:00  48   0   0   0   0    0   0   1
             ...
2022/08/15 00:00  43   0   0   0   0    0   0   1
```

This dataset has shape of `(49249, 8)`.

I am using data from 2017~2021 to train, and only 2022 would be used for test.

Using two days of data (`48 rows`), i need to forecast `x` in the next day. After changing this dataset to look like a supervised learning, i got a new **training** dataset with the shape `(1842, 55)`. `55` is because im using two days of data (`24+24`) plus the dummy variables represnting the day i want to make a forecast (`7` variables) `24+24+7 = 55`.

Now, according [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/) the `InputShape` of a `Conv1D` layer should have shape of `(batch_size, steps, input_dim)`.

So i did the following:

```
max_batch_size = 1824
steps = 48
input_dim = 55
```

So, i tried to reshaped it:

```
dataset = dataset.reshape(max_batch_size, steps, input_dim)
```

And i got this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 100320 into shape (1824,48,55)
```

I know this have been asked a lot, but i still don't understand it and none of the answers i have seen here have worked for me. How should i set my `InputLayer` to use with a `Conv1D` layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you are trying to solve a sequence problem, so if i got it true, you would need only the output values,
Make a list of values which are the outputs and then by

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(list_of_values)
```

take the list of values, you said you would need two days to forecast the next day; so based on that you should windowing the output of the function above with the window size of two days, and one day, so it would mean it will take 48 values and then forecast for 24 values on the next day. so  then;

```
data = data.window(window_size = 48 + 24, drop_remainder = True)
#set drop_remainder to true to drop sequences that are not in the same length as the others
```

the flat map and shuffle data as like as below

```
data = data.flat_map(lambda window : window.batch(48+24))
data = data.shuffle(shuffle_buffer)
```

now you should map data to separate the inputs and the outputs, somthing like as below

```
data = data.map(window : (window[:48], window[48:])
#by this way you set window size 48 values as the input and the others 24 values as the outputs (forecast)
```

and now set its batch size

```
data = data.batch(batch_size).prefetch()
```

now your data in windowed dataset which could be fed into convolution 1D and for the input layer there are two methods;
you could set input shape into (48,) and then define lambda layer with lambda which reshape or expand dimensions or even set the input shape equal to (48,1) and after that it would fed into Conv1D layer

Notice
In your case, by this way, the model would get 48 values in any format as i mean from each time of a day, but if your model would get its inputs from certain time for example 12 AM, so it would need to define `shift` parameter in window function and set it equal to 24 to take certain 24 values of each day from 12 AM

Comment: Following your explanation, and considering the one-hot-encoded variables, wich i have to use as input to my model, it should be `(55,1)` instead of `(48,1)`. But i still don't understand, shouldn't it be `(1,55)`? Since, according to Keras, the input shape is in format `(steps, input_dim)`? And why `steps = 1`? Shouldn't it be `steps = 48`? Since i am using two days of data?

Comment: notice that steps here `(steps, input_dim)` refers to the sequence length, which mean the length of each sequence which would feed into model, but the term steps which is in your mind is the windowing options, if you try out to window dataset, you would realize the steps in here `data = data.window(window_size = 48 + 24, drop_remainder = True)` i left it as default which is set to 1, same as what you mentioned here in comments.

Comment: for more details checkout this link [tf.data.Dataset ](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) more details about `shift` and `stride` parameter

Comment: for the input_shape it would be better to read more details about recurrent layers and convolution layers architecture and how these layers convert data with defined shape into the other shape, for example recurrent layers convert dim into units, so the output shape of the recurrent layers would be in shape `(None, sequence_length, units)` if set return_sequences = True, and `(None, units)` if you set return_sequences = False.

Comment: and for the input shape, its a rule for nat lang, sequences and image process, notice the input shape would have been in shape `(batch_size, sequence_length, dim)` and so on for image cause of two directions we would have in this shape `(batch_size, height, width, dim)` and basically tensorflow defines `batch_size` itself equal to None, and so what you should define is only `(sequence_length, dim)` for nat-lang and sequences, `(height, width, dim)` for images. also you could even define batch_size in input_shape by set it to None, and tensorflow would recognize it refers to batch_size.

Comment: Oh, that `step` term was really confusing me... i guess i understand now. Just changed my input shape according to that, and it works. Thanks!